# select element not showing well formed in web page

Tags: css, html

I'm having a graphical problem with a select box in a page of my website.

The problem is that the option elements of the select is showing inline instead as a drop-down selection. This strange behaviour becomes only if I render the select element inside a form element. (??I don't know why??)

The HTML output produces:

```
<form name="add-user-form" method="POST" action="/index.php/admin/happen/add"><p><select name="day" required><option value>d</option>
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
</select>
</p>
</form>
```

is a valid html5 markup, checked on w3c website.

this is an image showing the problem..
[image: select element visualization problem]

I omit the php code for now, somebody know this problem?

Comment: Do you have any CSS linked to this ?

Comment: Definitely CSS problem

Comment: You hit the problem... I have a css rule of form[name] * { display: inline-block; }  Damn!!!

Comment: I'll add an answer so you can put the question as resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we said in the comment, the issue is due to a CSS class using the following :

```
form[name] * {
 display: inline-block; 
}
```